# Count and order by relation with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

How can I use Eloquent to count the number of `comments` from a `post` and order the `posts` by number of `comments`?

My code is something like this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

I need to retrieve a collection of posts ordered by number of comments in an elegant way, thus I would prefer not to use something like `DB::select(select count(comment.post_id), post.id from posts left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id group by post.id order by count(post.id))`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `withCount` to retrieve relation count and order it with `orderBy(*_count)`. Something like,

```
Post::withCount('comments')->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')->get()
```

Comment: Thank you, I used dd($posts) and notice that indeed there is a new attribute with the name comments_count. It's exactly what I was looking for.